# Primefaces datatable sort has strange behavior after filtering the table

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, jsf-2.2

We use primeface 5.1, JSF 2.2 for our project. 
I have a problem in the primefaces datatable, after filtering the datatable, the sort will be broken, no record will show in the datatable if trying to sort the table. The following is the jsf code and the issue snapshot.

```
<p:dataTable id="myTable" var="model" value="#{myBean.dynaModels}" widgetVar="tableWidget" editable="true" styleClass="ui-dyna-table" 
         rows="10" paginator="true" resizableColumns="true" tableStyle="width:auto" filterEvent="enter" emptyMessage="No service order found"
         paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown} {CurrentPageReport}" draggableColumns="true"
         currentPageReportTemplate="{startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords}" paginatorPosition="top" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,50,100" style="margin-right: 5px"> 
<f:facet name="header">
    <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Columns" style="float:right" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
    <p:columnToggler datasource="myTable" trigger="toggler" />
</f:facet>
<c:forEach items="#{myBean.columnProperties}" var="columnProperty" >
    <p:column headerText="#{columnProperty.descr}" rendered="#{columnProperty.componentType.value eq 'S1'}" filterBy="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}" 
              sortBy="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}" filterMatchMode="exact">
        <f:facet name="filter" >
            <p:selectOneMenu style="width:111px" onchange="PF('tableWidget').filter()" >
                <f:selectItem itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                <f:selectItems value="#{columnProperty.lov}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}"  />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{columnProperty.descr}" rendered="#{columnProperty.componentType.value eq 'TXT'}" filterBy="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}" 
              sortBy="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
        <h:outputText value="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}"  />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{columnProperty.descr}" rendered="#{columnProperty.componentType.value eq 'DT'}" filterBy="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}" sortBy="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}">
        <f:facet name="filter" >
            <p:calendar  showOn="button" onchange="PF('tableWidget').filter()" >
            </p:calendar>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{model.dyanModelMap[columnProperty.propertyKey].value}"  />
    </p:column>
</c:forEach>
```

[image: Snapshot for the issue]

Answer (score 2):

Add and implement the filteredValue attribute in datatable. That fixed it for me.

Comment: You were/are using plain 5.1? Not an elite release? Iirc, it was fixed in an elite release. And if possible, please add some example code

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks. How in the heck one should know about this.. :) even after doing that and reading the (very limited) documentation about it I can't understand why it did the trick.